# How to best edit text in a .txt file for use with mysql

Tags: python, mysql, linux, shell

I am running a shell script that is collecting information from a handful of registers.  It is dumping the data into a text file as follows:  (I have placed the information in bold that I would like to upload)

log.txt:

> ID: 3498x39 
>  Time: **12:24:08** 
>  Date: **06/07/2015** 
>   4115 **134** (0x86) 
>  4116 **323** (0x143) 
>  4117 **20** (0x14)
>   
>  4118 **3** (0x3) 
>  4119 **26** (0x1A) 
>  4120 **1284**
>   (0x504)

Then repeats again with the next batch of data 10 minutes later.

What I would like to do now is update a MySQL database with this information after collecting it.  Would a python program be necessary to format the data to I think something like:

> 12:24:08    2015/06/07    134     323     20     3     26    1284

Or is there an easier way?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to ask, here. Do you mean you have a mysql table with a datetime field, and a separate field for each one of the register values (so, you have a 7-column table; 1 datetime followed by 6 ints), and you want to insert into that table? Or do you mean that you simply want to turn the above multiline string into the format below so that you can put that string into a mysql db? Because, if it's the latter, that'd be trivial even in bash. Hell, it may even be trivial in bash to do the latter, depending on whether the source of the data is trusted.

Comment: Simply transforming the strings into a reasonable format could be done using a simple `for` loop with `cut -d' ' -f2`.

Comment: perhaps you could use a regex with pythons re module to match and then reformat the data. Though you could probably do this with a shell script too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes the format is as you specified. So, it assumes any error output goes to stderr.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

output=""
read line # throw away the ID line
for ((i = 0; i != 9; ++i))
do
  read line
   formatted="$(echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f2)"
  case $i in
    1) formatted="$(echo "$formatted" | sed 's#\(\d+/\d+\)/\(\d+\)#\2/\1#')"
       ;;
    *) ;;
  esac
  output="$output $formatted"
done
echo "$output"
```

Running the above with what you had in your question as input.

```
bash-3.2$ ./test < input.txt
 12:24:08 06/07/2015 134 323 20 3 26 1284
```

Given the fact that the above was only 14 lines of code, could have been far shorter, and took ~2 minutes to write, I'm going to assume I must not have answered the question you were asking. Because, if this is the answer to your question, you asked a bad question.

Answer (score 0):

Python would be a fairly easy way to modify it. However, if you already have a shell script outputting it with that format, why not just modify the shell script to output it to the new format in log.txt or some alternative file? Of course, this doesn't fix the already existing records, but it would prevent the need for future log.txts to be converted.